# How to model data to avoid huge multi locations updates in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement group chat with Firebase. I read through many tutorials to learn how to organize the data properly. Right now my data looks like this.

```
groups : {
    group-1 : {
        members : {
          ... // list of members
        }
    }
}
membership : {
    user-1 : {
        ... // list of groups the user has joined
    }
}
conversations : {
    group-1 : {
       ... // messages in group 1 with timestamps etc
    }
}
```

Now I need to create notifications like this for users.

```
notifications : {
    user-1 : {
       // list of notifications for this user
    }
}
```

When someone sends a message in the group, I have to loop through the members and add a notification object under the 'notification/user-uid'

Is this approach scale-able with say a couple hundred members in the group or I am worrying too much with premature optimization.

Is there some way to model the notification node in a way to avoid so many writes to the database.